# Getting a random cell from a table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a random cell in jquery, between 1-16, I have the random number code in Javascript. Now what I want to do is to use that random number, and make the pointer of the table go to that random number? How would this be accomplished. Here is my random number code.

```
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)

    <table id="board" border="3" bgcolor="black"  align="center">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Shuffle" onclick="shuffle()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I actually should have said is reference, I want to get a reference to a random cell by using the random generator code in javascript

```
$('board tr td')
```

That should give me some way of entry in the table

Comment: Please take the time to provide more info, like the code for the table, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish. I don't know what "make the pointer of the table" means.

Comment: Just in case no one else mentions this, you target the table with an id of "board" using this jQuery selector `$('#board')`. Your code above is missing the hash #.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jQuery specific solution is to assign a click event to the button in javascript, and put **FiveTools** code solution there.

```
<input type="button" value="Shuffle" id="theButton"/>
```

javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

$('#theButton').click(function() {

    // Stores a random number from 0 to 15
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);

    // This brings you back up to a range of 1 to 16
    var actualNum = randomNum + 1;

    // Grabs and holds the table cell for that number
    // Example: number 10 would be third row, second column
    var randomtd = $('#board td').eq(randomNum);

    // Calculate and store which row
    // by dividing the generated number by the number of rows, and rounding up
    var whichRow = Math.ceil(actualNum / 4);

    // Calculate and store which column
   // by using modulo to find the remainder of the number divided by the rows
   // If the modulo result is '0', then set it to '4'
    var whichColumn = (actualNum % 4) == 0 ? 4 : (actualNum % 4);

    // Display results in an alert
    alert('theNumber: ' + actualNum + ' row: ' + whichRow + '  column: ' + whichColumn);

   // For fun, and to show that you have the td stored
   // Display the number in the correct td
   // and set the text color to grey, since the table is black
   randomtd.text(actualNum).css({color:'#DDD'});
});

});
```

Comment: I think instead of using `16`, I'd replace that with the number of `<td>`'s like this: `var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('td').length )` that way you can vary the table size and not have to change the code

Comment: @fudgey - Good idea. Makes it flexible. I'll add that option.

Comment: Well it did give randoms results but what i wanted is a way to get the radom cell, and also get the position of the random cell. Suppose I randomly get the number 10, then i also want to get to cell number 10 as well. Btw Im working with a 4x4 table.

Comment: Changing the background was just for illustration. When you click, the random number is stored in the randomNum variable, and the cell is referenced in the randomtd variable. You can delete the lines that have the comments after them, and do whatever you want with the table cell. When you say you want the position of the cell, what do you mean. The position on the page, or the row and column number?

Comment: What I mean was row and coloumn. If i want position ten, then it would be row 3, column 2. What I basically want is the random number to choose the random td, by getting a number out of 16.  Then I want to find what cell has that number, and make it my Td. Also,The eq function only goes up to 3 for some reason. Is there a way to get it up to 16?

Comment: Getting the row & col would simply be mathematics. I'll update my example. When you say 'find which cell has that number and make it my Td', I'm not sure what you mean. You already have the td stored in the randomtd variable. The only question is what you want to do with it. Beyond that, I don't know how to make it yours. As far as the eq function only going up to 3, I don't know what that means either. It will grab the item at the index of any number you give it. I'll have the updated example in a minute.

Comment: There was an error, I was subtracting 1 for randomNum. I shouldn't have. It is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
var randomtd = $('td').eq(randomNum - 1)